Unified syntax for SQL Server and Oracle to calculate standard deviation
Now for calculating standard deviation I use this query in Oracle
SELECT rating,
       STDDEV(duration) AS StD
FROM ratings
GROUP BY rating

and the following for SQL Server
SELECT rating,
       STDEV(duration) AS StD
FROM ratings
GROUP BY rating

But those differ only by a Std. Deviation function used - Oracle's STDDEV and SQL Server's STDEV.
How to unify this query, without using views, in both DBMSes? It's not allowing to create a custom aggregate function or use stdev in custom function in SQL Server. Could use package in Oracle if it would allow me to achieve that.

I wouldn't bother, very few things are the same between the two systems, so you will just end up redoing your work later if you try

Often nothing but the simplest queries are transferable between different products, and even then sometimes they aren't. They all have different dialects of SQL, and they can sometimes be vastly different. Writing bespoke solutions for each (R)DBMS is often the only way to go.

@siggemannen not willing to maintain both queries and to check a provider before execution.

SQL Server has STDEV (Transact-SQL) and Oracle has STDDEV. (Very easily found with Google)

Can you just create your own wrapper function in one of the databases, with the name from the other one (i.e. in Oracle create your own STDEV function that just returns the result of the built-in STDDEV)? (But agree trying to use the same code across two RDBMSs is probably more trouble that it's worth...)

@AlexPoole tried but at least sqlserver does not allow stdev to be used in a function

Their calculations are different which is why they give different results.

Oracle's STDDEV calculates the sample standard deviation (divides by N - 1).
SQL Server's STDEVP calculates the population standard deviation (divides by N)

To calculate manually using SQL common to both:
Sample Standard Deviation
SELECT
    rating,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN
        SQRT(
            (
                SUM(duration * duration) - POWER(SUM(duration), 2) / COUNT(*)
            ) / (COUNT(*) - 1)
        )
    ELSE
        NULL
    END AS StD
FROM ratings
GROUP BY rating;

Population Standard Deviation
SELECT
    rating,
    SQRT(
        (
            SUM(duration * duration) - POWER(SUM(duration), 2) / COUNT(*)
        ) / COUNT(*)
    ) AS StD
FROM ratings
GROUP BY rating;

